PHP Model Class
Does this usage make sense? Will it cause any problems later?
function model($folder, $file)
{
    global $db;
    if (is_file(path . 'app/models/' . $folder . '/' . $file . '.php')) {
        require_once(path . 'app/models/' . $folder . '/' . $file . '.php');
        return new $file($db);
    }
}

echo model('admin', 'common')->get();


That works fine since it's possible to instantiate class by a variable containing that class name.
But I suggest, if you can, to use composer to auto-load classes. You can find tutorial about that.

If you want to follow this path, you can optimize it a little bit with a static variable to make some cache and avoid some checks on the file system.
You could also create and retrieve a "singleton" instance if you want to.
Also, since you're using a global $db, use it directly in your model. There's no sense in passing global variables as arguments.
Note: I did not test this code, but if you have any questions about any logic, ask.
function model($folder, $file, bool $singleton = false, ...$modelParams)
{
    static $cache = [];

    if (\array_key_exists("$folder|$file", $cache)) {
        if ($singleton) {
            return $cache["$folder|$file"]['instance'];
        }
        
        return new $file(...$modelParams);
    }

    if (is_file(path . 'app/models/' . $folder . '/' . $file . '.php')) {
        require_once(path . 'app/models/' . $folder . '/' . $file . '.php');
        if (class_exists($file)) {
            $cache["$folder|$file"]['instance'] = new $file(...$modelParams);
            
            return new $file(...$modelParams);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Class not found on file.");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Model file not found.");
        
    }
}

try {
    echo model('admin', 'common')->get();
} catch (Exception $error) {
    echo $error;
}

